# Javascript: Adding $ + cents

Tags: javascript, numbers, numeric

A short while ago I had posted about adding a comma to the value once it reached a certain number (1000).

At the moment, the value is going up $11 every second, although I would like to implement a change so that it goes up $11.43 every second.

For example: 0, $11.43, $22.86 ... and then when it reaches $1000 it should have the comma ($1,024.56). You should get the drift.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9cey/14/

```
var millisecs = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#badge');
    var num = parseInt($badge.text().replace(',', ''))+11;
    $badge.text(num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
}, millisecs);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: And the best answer there IMHO was [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to add $11.43. However, there are two problems:

- avoid inserting commas after the decimal point.
- rounding errors due to floating point

To address both of these, I suggest the following:

1. Do everything in cents. So add 1143 (not 11.43)
2. To format, first convert the number to a string, then split the string into a prefix and the last two characters. Put commas into the prefix, then add a period and the last two characters.

Oh, and you'll need to do a couple of other things:

- get rid of the `badge-support-text` span that you have in your fiddle, since you're going to be adding in the cents explicitly
- strip out the decimal point as well as the commas before you parse the current amount. You might also consider creating a closure that maintains its own internal data that is incremented, so you don't have to parse.

Here's a modification of your jsfiddle that does the above (except the closure):

```
var millisecs = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#badge');
    var num = (parseInt($badge.text().replace(/[,.]/g, ''))+1143).toString();
    var dollars = num.substring(0, num.length-2);
    var cents = num.substr(-2);
    $badge.text(dollars.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + cents);
}, millisecs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok i'm not too familiar with javascript although this is what i'm thinking.

Convert the number to a string: 

    var num = 1143;
    var n = num.toString();

Split the string into prefix:

Having trouble...

Put commas into the prefix

Not sure

Add a period and the last 2 characters.

Not sure

Comment: @user1628845 - I added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5FBx/) that shows how it should look. this is just one way to do it

```
var millisecs = 10;
setInterval(function() {
  var $badge = $('#badge');

  var num = parseFloat($badge.text().replace(',', ''))+11.34;
  num = num.toFixed(2);

  var numString = num.toString().split('.');

  var dollars = numString[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  var cents = numString[1];

  var str = [dollars, cents].join('.');

  $badge.text( str );
}, millisecs);
```